# Why is this hidden div not showing in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I've made a page which should show a div when the user clicks on a input text box. The div will contain more information about the required input, etc. The page works fine on FireFox and the div shows, but when using IE the div just doesn't show. It seems like I've tried everything and nothing has worked so far. This is the [page](http://beta.d-load.org/web/register.php). Maybe you could look at the source and see what I'm doing wrong? If you need me to upload the source as a text file, I can do that.

Comment: Hmmm... don't have access to IE right now, but it looks fine. Works on Chrome, though. Weird.

Comment: It is weird! I never tried it on Chrome, but I'm glad to know it works (Even though it's a little out of line). I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Shows just fine for me in IE6, IE8 and IE8 in IE7/compatibility mode.  Might want to use alpha image loader filter for transparency in IE6 though ;-)

Comment: The title is great, it certainly does nothing to hide that you need help on a very basic level. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried on IE 8 and it works fine - what version of IE are you using?  Try clearing your cache and restarting the browser!

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! Sorry I should have thought of that. Well, that was a waste of my time, trying to fix something that didn't need fixing. Also a waste of yours! Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: No worries - I've spent ages doing the same thing myself :)  glad I could help!